# How to increase the size grid.arrange(tableGrob, ggplotGrob)

Tags: r, gridextra

Recently started using grid/gridExtra and been trying to figure how to increase the size of the grobs. Not sure why, there seems to be a lot of real estate edge space left on paper. How to increase the size? Below is the PDF produce by knitr and rmarkdown.

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: pdf_document
classoption: landscape
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(gridExtra)
library(ggplot2)
a <- read.csv(text='"State","Abbreviation", "age"
"Alabama","AL", "7"
"Alaska","AK", "8"
"Arizona","AZ", "3"
"Arkansas","AR", "4"
"California","CA", "4"')

tbla <- tableGrob(a, )
tblb <- ggplotGrob(ggplot(cars, aes(dist, speed)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=loess))
grid.arrange(tbla, tblb)
```
````

Comment: which grob do you want bigger, the table, or the plot? The figure itself is limited by the knitr options fig.width/fig.height, but it's unclear what margins you want reduced.

Comment: Hi Baptiste, I have tried adjusting knitr options fig.width/fig.height, but the the size of the image seem to be about the same where the edge of the image is still very far away from the edge of the document. Is there a way I can adjust the size of the image like how we insert an image in a MS Powerpoint and enlarge it as far as near the edge of the powerpoint slide? Does this have anything do with viewpoint?

Comment: the margins in the pdf document have more to do with knitr/rmarkdown, but your question still isn't very well defined. What exactly do you want? Figures that touch the edge of the page? A table that extends as much as the plot? A self-contained figure, or included in a pdf document? My guess is that you could tweak the pdf margins by passing layout options to the geometry package via rmarkdown/pandoc.

Comment: sorry, I left the question at the bottom of the posting. This comment area is not large enough to show the image.

Comment: sorry, I left the question at the bottom of the posting. This comment area is not large enough to show the image. 

Yes, I am looking to enlarge the image close to the edge as much as possible, because the image (tables and chart) is too small and therefore very difficult to see small tables and charts. How can I stretch the image edge close to the document edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the margins via rmarkdown, using the geometry package

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_width: 11
    fig_height: 7
    fig_crop: false
classoption: landscape
geometry: margin=0in
---


```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(gridExtra)
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
a <- read.csv(text='"State","Abbreviation", "age"
"Alabama","AL", "7"
"Alaska","AK", "8"
"Arizona","AZ", "3"
"Arkansas","AR", "4"
"California","CA", "4"')

tbla <- tableGrob(a)
tblb <- ggplotGrob(ggplot(cars, aes(dist, speed)) + geom_point() + geom_smooth(method=loess))
grid.arrange(tbla, tblb, heights=unit.c(sum(tbla$heights), unit(1,"null")))
```
````

Comment: That worked! I need to look into the geometry package a little more. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: BTW... geometry: margin=0in works on the left and right margin is there a top and bottom margin? also, is there a way to enlarge the table as well to the same size as the chart at the bottom?

Comment: you can set the widths explicitly, `tbla <- tableGrob(a, widths=unit(rep(1/ncol(a), ncol(a)),"npc")-unit(1,"line"))
`